# Displaying payment page in Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, back-button, inappbrowser

Basically, I have an Ionic v1 app(android&IOS), Here I am trying to display a payment page inside the app by using `inappbrowser`. When the user clicks "Paynow", it will open the payment page.

Once the user entered to `inappbrowser`, the hardware back buttons need to be prevented.

What I tried,

`document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);`

`cordova.InAppBrowser.open(myPaymentUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes');`

```js
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Is there any other logic to display the web page & prevent back button?

Comment: what does **"prevent back button"** mean exactly? Do you want to prevent only going back to the previous page? Or do you want to prevent also closing the inappbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **InAppBrowserOptions** with **hardwareback** property. You have to set value **YES or NO**.

[More details here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)